# Circular show with previous and next buttons

Tags: c#, winforms

Say I have a list: 1 5 6 10

When I click on next and the List item showed is already 10.. I want to bring the user back to 1 and same in the other way when I click previous and the List item showed is already 1.. I want to bring the user back to 10..  Here is what I tried but I always get that the "i (contor) can't be negative or greater than List.Count" :

```
public int i = 0;

    private void nextbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ++i;
        if (sweaterclicked)
        {
            if(SweatersList.Count != 1)
            if (i >= SweatersList.Count - 1)
            {
                i = 0;
                pictureBox1.Image = SweatersList[i];
            }
            else pictureBox1.Image = SweatersList[i];
        }
    }

    private void previousbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        --i;
        if (sweaterclicked)
        {
            if (SweatersList.Count != 1)
            {
            if (i < 0)
            {
                i = SweatersList.Count;
                pictureBox1.Image = SweatersList[i];
            }
            else pictureBox1.Image = SweatersList[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which `if`s are those `else`s meant to belong to?

Comment: second `if` with first `else` which means that `else` belongs to `if(i < 0)`

Comment: @EdPlunkett edited it for you. See the update!

Comment: Thanks for the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array or list indexes in C# start at zero, so the largest in-range index is *one less than the count of items in the collection*. Therefore, `SweatersList.Count`, hence `i`, is out of range here:

```
i = SweatersList.Count;
pictureBox1.Image = SweatersList[i];
```

So when you want to start over at the last valid index, you need to subtract one from `SweatersList.Count`:

```
i = SweatersList.Count - 1;
```

I don't know why you're incrementing and decrementing outside the `if (sweaterclicked)` blocks, but I presume you do.

Comment: Yeah works just fine now, One more add is at next button here : `if (i >= SweatersList.Count - 1)` it has to be `if (i > SweatersList.Count - 1)` .

Comment: @A.Ispas Good catch!